# Init.d script to let Kate/Texteditor wait for loading files from USB stick until it is mounted

Tags: mount, init.d

I have all my programming stuff on a USB stick. Sometimes I forget to put the USB stick back in when I open up the laptop again, e.g. resume the session with the files from the USB stick open.

I do have a script that does that for my NAS for mounting

```
mount -t cifs
```

Is the same possible for mounting with my USB stick and text-editors?

Doesn't have to be an init.d script. I don't know what else would be viable. It's just an example because the script that I have installed is an init.d script and does the job.

Thanks

von Spotz

Comment: What OS & release are you talking about?  Are you talking about a *live* system, or is the thumb-drive an additional drive you've mounted during operation of the OS on your laptop, what *file-system* is it? are you un-mounting it first?

Comment: Hello Tejas, I am talking about Kubuntu 20.04 running from the hard drive. Only my sourcee code is on the USB stick. Thanks, good wishes.